# Javascript shopping cart logic

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a javascript function that currently adds the item price (of a product, in this case pizza)  into a shopping cart and then  multiplies it by the quantity of items to return the  total amount. This part works fine however I now need functionality to be able to change the price of each additional item after the first to $5. Right now I can only seem to change them all to $5 but not each additional one after the original as seen below in the second code block. How can I get this to work?

The original function (which works like a charm)

```
 getItemTotal(item) {
  let total = item.price * item.quantity;
  item.options.forEach(option => (total += option.value * item.quantity));
  return total;
   }
```

My solution (which changes every item price to $5 and not each additional item after the first item)

```
getItemTotal(item) {
if(item.tags == "pizza"){
  item.price = 5;
}
```

Comment: As per your logic item with tag pizza will set a price of 5 and I read you have different requirements. the good question to ask is how do you identify this is an additional item ? by tags? if yes then instead of pizza check if item.tags=='additionItem' then add the price.

Comment: That is a good question. That's what i've been trying to wrap my brain around. Each item has a tag, like pizza, or pasta, or sandwich, but instead of creating a separate screen with additional items priced differently, I would just like the logic to say if item.quanity is greater than 1 then each additional item after the 1st is $5

Comment: I was thinking something like `if  (item.tags == "pizza"&&(item.quantity >2 )) {  item.price = 5;} `   but the greteater sign does not work at all and when i change it to equals the math is way off

Comment: check If you have quantity > 2  in the data for pizza  :) (item.tags == "pizza" && item.quantity > 2) will also work. operator

Answer (score 0):

@user269867 was correct in assuring me that this code will work.

```
 if (item.tags == "pizza"&&(item.quantity >2 )) { item.price = 5;}
```

I just had to adjust the item.price based upon the condition multiple times for it to work in my use case.

```
 if(item.tags == "pizza" && item.quantity === 2){
  item.price = 4.99;
 }
 else if (item.tags == "pizza" && item.quantity === 3){
      item.price = 4.65;
    }`
```

Thanks for listening :)